# How to select two columns from multiple tables

Tags: postgresql, python

I want to select two columns from multiple tables using `psycopg`. Although join or union may work for this purpose, I am looking for the way, which can read more tables at once.

My thought is to get the table list first, and then use a loop to read in each table sequentially. However, it does not work. Any other hint or thought?

Here is my code.

```
try:
    con = psycopg2.connect(database='****', user='****', password = '****', host='****', port = ****)
    con.autocommit = True
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'public' ORDER BY table_name ASC;")
    tablename=cur.fetchall()


    for x in tablename:
        cur.execute("SELECT column1, column2 FROM %s ORDER BY column1 ASC", (x))
        mytest = cur.fetchall()

except psycopg2.DatabaseError, e:
if con: 
    con.rollback()

print 'Error %s' % e    
sys.exit(1)


finally: 

if con:
        con.close()
```

Here is the error message.

```
Error syntax error at or near "'table1'"

LINE 1: SELECT column1, column2 FROM 'table1' ORDER BY ...

                                 ^
```

Comment: This seems to me to be pretty easy in Python: just create a new list and append the results of each query. Note that this will still result in the tables being queried *sequentially*. If you want to read them *at the same time* you'll need to use multiple threads (or similar parallel processing) and query different tables in each thread. However, *why* do you want to do that? I presume you just want to avoid doing the `union`?

Comment: @Colin'tHart I have over 100 tables, and it should be time-consuming to do union table by table. I put the error message in. It seems that I create the wrong data type for the postgresql query, but outside the string, I am not sure how to revise the code.

Comment: You're sending in the table name as a parameter when what you want is actual string substitution. What the parameterization is doing is converting it to a text data type because it thinks you want to pass table1 as a filter value.

Comment: What is the point of this task? Is it an administrative report? An externally-facing website?

Comment: @swasheck The task is to get a series of geographical coordinates from postgresql tables. What you said is exactly what I want. So, is there anyway to fix the error? Or any thought?

Comment: This usually means a database design problem. If you have a huge bunch of tables with the same or common structure, you probably haven't normalized your data properly. Or you might be doing schema sharding, I guess...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry! My fault! I found the solution for that.

The python string should be absolutely clear without any format, like "" or '' for the string substitution in the postgresql code.

Here is the revised code.

```
try:
    con = psycopg2.connect(database='****', user='****', password = '****', host='****', port = ****)
    con.autocommit = True
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'public' ORDER BY table_name ASC;")
    tablename=cur.fetchall()


    for x in tablename:
        for y in x:
            cur.execute("SELECT column1, column2 FROM {mytable} ORDER BY column1 ASC". format(mytable=y))
            mytest = cur.fetchall()

except psycopg2.DatabaseError, e:
    if con: 
        con.rollback()

    print 'Error %s' % e    
    sys.exit(1)


finally: 

    if con:
            con.close()
```

Thanks for helping once again!